# Scroll Treeview to Bottom automatically in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, scroll

I got a treeview with a bunch of nodes where more gets added over time. When I add a new node to the treeview, I need to make sure that the very bottom most node is visible.

I tried using the ItemContainerGenerator to select the last item and bring it into view. But it doesn't work for me.

How can I make my treeview scroll to the very last item?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with TreeViewItem in code, I think you can use `treeViewItem.BringIntoView()` which should cause the scrollable area the item is in to scroll so that it is visible.

## Edits

### Examples

```
    view.SchemaUpdateGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.UserState);
```

The above like is from a BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event handler.  e.UserState contains the currently working object (custom class), not a grid row.  The grid automatically translates the object into the item.

Comment: Yeah but how do i get the TreeViewItem? Cause if I do: ReportTreeView.Items[ReportTreeView.Items.Count - 1] - It gives me the item itself (the Report class that I created) and not a TreeViewItem. I tried using ((TreeViewItem)ReportTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator(ReportTreeView.Items[ReportTreeView.Items.Count - 1])).BringIntoView() - But the itemcontainergenerator is returning null.

Comment: I think you should just be able to use the object without casting.  See above for a previous implementation of mine.

Comment: No I cant - If I cast as Report object. It wont let me bring into view. And I can't cast ReportTreeView.Items[0] as a treeview item.